# Too..to & such in expressing results

Tags: expressions, differences, such

It was....hard question to solve

a) too
b) such a

I’m a little bit confused but i think the form (too + adj+ to) can’t have a noun after the adjective unless it’s (too + adj+ a/an + noun), also I haven’t seen the form (such + adj +noun+ to) before.. I’m just guessing so what should it be?

Comment: Neither of your proposed alternatives results in something that fits standard grammar rules.

Comment: And if it’s “such a”?

Comment: @Belle You are correct. (1) *It was too hard **a** question to solve.* (2) *It was such **a** hard question to solve.*  Note, however, that this is possible: "*It was **too** a hard question to solve!*" The emphasis and intonation now makes the first version possible in a way that's idiomatically unacceptable when it's just a simple statement. (It's also using *too* in a difference sense, one that's synonymous with *also*.)

Comment: In neither sentence, however, should the indefinite article be omitted.